# How to increase the scope of US ASCII charset without breaking the ASCII - based code?

Tags: java, file, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I'm openning a file with

```
private String getStringFromFile(File file) {
    try {
        return Files.readString(Paths.get(file.getPath()), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while reading: " + file.getName());
        return "";
    }
}
```

and even though the file seems to be clearly ASCII compatible, I'm getting `Error while reading: fileName`.

The file looks like this:

[image]

The code works if I manually delete the header (the part with square brackets) before openning it (I'm deleting them anyway in the code later). Is there a way of extending the scope of charsets while not breaking the code I have which works only on ASCII or is this some kind of rare exception?

[Here's](https://filebin.net/6hubvyc5pr37w4y6) the file in pgn (it can be openned as txt).

Comment: Try using ISO_8859_1 - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#ISO_8859_1 instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Still can't open it.

Comment: Show full exception, please.

Comment: I tried to print it out in ten different ways, but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is almost in ASCII. The problem is with the *quote* character in `'Cote d’Ivoire'.

The file contains a 0x92 byte. In Windows code page 1252 (West European Languages) it is the Unicode character U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK.

The problem is that the 1252 code page is a slight variation from ISO-8859-1 which uses unmapped position for some common characters like the euro symbol `€` and the right and left quotation marks. And it is not in the list of the *always present* charsets.

How to fix:

- if your system supports the `win1252` or `cp1252` charset, use it.
- else, you should use a `FilterInputStream` to replace the non-ascii characters for example with a space (ASCII 0x20) or from a custom Map (0x92 -> 0x27 to replace the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`’`) with a simple APOSTROPHE (`'`)). After that, the `InputStreamReader` will give you the expected characters.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bad idea to add win1252? I mean the whole "if your system supports" is kinda scary. The app isn't going to stay on Windows.